Why didn't std::copy to overflow the buffer; only got clang sanitizer warning "Undefined Behavior"?
I was concerned about a std::copy line in a code review. I ran clang sanitizers on it and it confirmed the smell. I went into the debugger and saw that the copy did not overflow into the next field in the structure as I expected, and I do not understand why that is the case.
In below program, in the std::copy, the 8 was intended to represent the 8 elements (of type long); but, the type of src.arr[0] is pointer to long[4]. So, I expected the 8 to try to copy 8 long[4] items thereby overflowing the array following arr; i.e., the overflowArray field. But in my test, it did not, and in the reviewed program it also worked without overflowing.
In below program is following line that clang reports as Undefined Behavior but currently gives desired results. One important question: Can this code on a different platform and/or compiler result in incorrect results.?
std::copy(src.arr[0], src.arr[0] + 8, dst.arr[0]);


#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstring>

struct Astruct
{
    long arr[2][4];
    long overflowArray[8];
};

void printAstruct(Astruct str)
{
    std::cout << "arr: ";
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for( size_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << str.arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << ";  overflowArray: ";
    for( size_t k = 0; k < 8; ++k)
    {
        std::cout << str.overflowArray[k] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void fillArray(Astruct& );

int main()
{
    Astruct src{};
    Astruct dst{};

    std::cout << "src size: " << sizeof(src.arr) << "; dst size:" << sizeof(src.overflowArray) << std::endl;
    // SETUP
    std::cout << "dst before copy" << std::endl;
    printAstruct(dst);
    long* srcStart = &src.arr[0][0];
    memset(srcStart, 0xFF, sizeof(src.arr));

    std::cout << "src:" << std::endl;
    printAstruct(src);
    
    // the Smell: src.arr[0] is type: array of 4 longs:
    std::copy(src.arr[0], src.arr[0] + 8, dst.arr[0]); // <--  Undefined Behavior

    std::cout << "\ndst after copy:" << std::endl;
    printAstruct(dst);
}

Output:
src size: 32; dst size:32
dst before copy
arr: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ;  overflowArray: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
src:
arr: -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ;  overflowArray: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

dst after copy:
arr: -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ;  overflowArray: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  <-- I expected these 0's to be overwritten

It appears that I was correct in seeing a smell as confirmed by clang sanitizer, but I do not understand why the overflow did not occur, since 8 should have advanced the end address past the 8 longs.
Ran clang with sanitizers and confirmed the smell:
runtime error: index 8 out of bounds for type 'long[4]'
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior

Why wasn't overflowArray overwritten? Could it be overwritten in another platform and/or compiler?
I changed the code to:
std::copy(&src.arr[0][0], &src.arr[0][0] + 8, &dst.arr[0][0]); 

since &src.arr[0][0] is a pointer to long.
But was told this was too confusing, and the addresses are the same in both the orignal or in my change.

"I expected these 0's to be overwritten" -- Overwritten by what? The 0's in the source?

The warning is about overflowing arr[0] into arr[1], not about overflowing arr into overflowArray.  C++ does not allow flattening  multidimensional arrays like that.

"8 should have advanced the end address past the 8 longs."  That assumption seems to be your mistake.  arr[0] decays to a long*.  arr[0], arr[0] + 8 is exactly the range of your array.

You have the same value repeated multiple places, so it can be hard to see what's copied where. I'd suggest initializing each element to a different value. For example, src.arr could hold the values 0 through 7, src.overflowArray could hold 10 through 17, dst.arr could hold the values 20 through 27, dst.overflowArray could hold 30 through 37 (before the copy).

@PaulH These expressions src.arr[0], src.arr[0] + 8 reinterpret the two-dimensional array  long arr[2][4]; like one-dimensional array with 8 elements of the type long because the expression src.arr[0] having the type long[4] is implicitly converted to a pointer of the type long * and points to the first element of the type long of the two-dimensional array.

src.arr is an array of 2 objects. Those objects just happen to be arrays of 4 objects. So src.arr[0] is an array of 4 objects.  src.arr[0] + 8 instructs  std::copy to copy 8 objects from the array of 4 objects. Practically there are 8 objects all in a row, but the walls of src.arr[0] are breached by writing into the object at src.arr[1].  Extremely impolite, but a case of undefined behaviour that usually works as expected. Assuming you expect src.arr[0] to overflow into ``src.arr[1]and not intooverflowArray`.

I went into the debugger and saw that the copy did not overflow into the next field in the structure as I expected The copy did overlow into the next array element in the structure src.arr[1].  Change the +8 to +9 for more adventures in undefined behavior.

The nature of undefined behaviour is that the behaviour is (well) not defined.   No particular outcome is required, no particular outcome is guaranteed, and any outcome is possible - even if it doesn't make sense to a mere mortal.

Crux of my issue: Given T* ptr; Then ptr+N has an address = ptr + N*sizeof(T). Thought Clang was saying: T is long[4]. So I thought ptr+8 would be ptr+8sizeof(long[4]), which is a lot more than ptr+8sizeof(long). So that seems to be consistent with the clang warning index 8 out of bounds for type 'long[4]'.

@Peter Does the UB in this case mean that on a different platform and/or compiler, the UB could result in a wrong answer?

I added: auto* ptr1 = src.arr[0]; and auto* ptr2 = src.arr[0] + 8; No decay here, right? Anyway, subtracting the hex values gives 0x20 = 32 bytes, which is the desired value. So my question really appears to be at top-level, not in the call to std::copy where we have decay.

What is also strange is that if I just use auto instead of auto*, hovering over auto gives long and not long*. Of course replacing auto with long does not work - must use long*. So, is clang incorrect that the type is long[4]?

I updated the OP with the most important question that was not clearly addressed with a distinct yes or no (although some did give the definition of UB.) - Can this code on a different platform and/or compiler result in incorrect results? I am beginning to think that clang made a mistake in their run-time analysis by indicating UB and thinking that, in light of my recent non-decaying experiments, that this code is portable to other platforms and/or compilers.

@user4581301 Rereading all comments and yours, a bit is sinking in. Clang looking microscopically at the array of 4 objects and sees an overflow and reports UB. Maybe with AI in future, clang would understand the intent from context, and ask, to be sure, that the code intends to overflow into ``src.arr[1]`. Thanks all for your help. I think the original code is portable. I still prefer my version since it gets down to a single element in the array.

@PaulH  Any code with undefined behaviour can (but is not guaranteed to) exhibit different observable behaviour on a different platform or with a different compiler.   One possible example of that is "correct" results with one platform/compiler and "incorrect" results with another.   Another possible example is "correct" results with one platform/compiler and - with another platform/compiler - reformatting the system drive.

Lets look at your struct.
struct Astruct
{
  long arr[2][4];
  long overflowArray[8];
};

it looks like this:
arr[0][0] arr[0][1] arr[0][2] arr[0][3]
arr[1][0] arr[1][1] arr[1][2] arr[1][3]
ovrflw[0] ovrflw[1] ovrflw[2] ovrflw[3] ovrflw[4] ovrflw[5] ovrflw[6] ovrflw[7]

there are 8 longs for arr[][] and then 8 longs for overflowArray (I made it shorter for spacing purposes).
Now, what is going on here:
// the Smell: src.arr[0] is type: array of 4 longs:
std::copy(src.arr[0], src.arr[0] + 8, dst.arr[0]); // <--  Undefined Behavior

so, src.arr[0] is of type long[4].  However, the first argument of std::copy is a value parameter.  So it is being passed by value.
When you pass a long[4] by value, it decays into long* pointing to the first element of the array.
Similarly, when you do src.arr[0]+8 it says "ok, adding long[4] with an int.  That makes no sense!  Let's try decaying!" and it again converts the long[4] into a long* pointing at the first element of the array.
Going back to the memory:
\/ decay of arr[0] points here
arr[0][0] arr[0][1] arr[0][2] arr[0][3]
arr[1][0] arr[1][1] arr[1][2] arr[1][3]
\/ arr[0]+8 points here
ovrflw[0] ovrflw[1] ovrflw[2] ovrflw[3] ovrflw[4] ovrflw[5] ovrflw[6] ovrflw[7]

Now, this is violating part of the C++ standard; in particular, we have a pointer into an array of length 4 and we are advancing 8 steps.
In practice treading [2][4] arrays like [8] arrays works.  If some wording in the C++ standard says this isn't allowed?  Compilers ignore it.  The use of [a][b][c] arrays (with compile time constant size) as variants of [a*b*c] arrays is far too common in C and C++ code bases to enforce any kind of UB here.
If you accept that you can treat long arr[2][4] as a contiguous block of 8 longs, then arr[0] through arr[0]+8 (once suitably decayed) are indeed pointers to the start and one-past-the-end of this block of memory.

I see your point. But, UB could mean different results on a different platform/compiler. Other comments indicate no problem. So, why does clang report. So, why does clang report "runtime error: index 8 out of bounds for type 'long[4]'"

@PaulH UB is UB; it means the C++ standard no longer constrains the behavior of any part of your program.  A given compiler is free to do whatever it wants, including try to protect you from yourself.  As for clang's error: Index 8 is indeed out of bounds for type long[4].  And you are accessing index 8 (well, creating a pointer to it) of a 4 element array.  Until the C++ standard permits long[a][b][c] to be treated as long[a*b*c] you are on thin ice, despite clang not making your hard drive explode.

As seen by the function the decay occurs. But before the call, are just addresses. Crux of my issue: In general,
given T* ptr, then ptr+N has an address = ptr + Nsizeof(T). Clang says T long[4]. So I thought ptr+8 would be ptr+8sizeof(long[4]), which is a lot more than ptr+8*sizeof(long); and the former would be out-of-bounds whereas ther later fits in correctly. I am still confused if the above statement is correct.

Bottom line. Even if confused,  I'd like to know one thing: Is [0] just as portable as my recommendation using &[0][0]? Can the former give incorrect results on a different platform and/or compiler?

@PaulH Yes it can give unexpected results. The implementors of the compiler could build in runtime checks to ensure arrays are not breached and abort the program. To do so is both helpful and a perfectly valid interpretation. You'll see behaviour like this in debug builds of some of the library containers. Extending it to a raw array would be tricky, but do-able for cases where the origin of the array hasn't been too obscured by pointer decay. Since clang can detect this is a problem at compile time, it could easily produce an executable that stops at 4 elements, also a valid implementation.

FYI-Clang reported it in runtime as the code was instrumented with clang sanitizers.

@PaulH The type of arr[0] is long[4] not long(*)[4].  When arr[0] decays, it decays to long* not long(*)[4].  arr[0]+8 is thus 8 longs later, not 8 long[4]s later.  Array types do not decay to a pointer to the array, they decay to a pointer to the array's first element.  Now, if you pass arr directly, that is of type long[2][4] which could decay into long(*)[4].  So arr+8 is 32 long's ahead of arr.

I don't have standard at hand to search exactly what happened here but it looks like the arrays were decayed into pointer. One can easily check that by creating the wrapper around copy and printing its signature:
template<typename II, typename OI>
void wrapped_copy(II b, II e, OI dst)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    std::copy(b, e, dst);
}

The above prints:
void wrapped_copy(II, II, OI) [with II = long int*; OI = long int*]

when called as below:
wrapped_copy(src.arr[0], src.arr[0] + 8, dst.arr[0]);

I can only speculate that's because std::copy (and the wrapper above) take the parameters by value and don't have overload for the reference to an array. The reference to an long[4] array just decays to a pointer to the first element. Then the second parameter correctly calculates the end iterator by adding 8 which is the size of long[2][4] array.
Would I write this like that? Likely not - it IS confusing like hell.

What is the point of striking out text instead of deleting it? It makes your answer look sloppy.
